# I have a problem with Expo. I can't figure it out because I'm a beginner

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

I have some problems with expo. When I was init an app then I got this warns:

```
npm install
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: use-subscription@1.6.0
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (react-dom, react-native, react-native-web)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^18.0.0" from use-subscription@1.6.0
npm WARN node_modules/use-subscription
npm WARN   use-subscription@"^1.0.0" from react-native@0.64.3
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^18.0.0" from use-subscription@1.6.0
npm WARN   node_modules/use-subscription
npm WARN     use-subscription@"^1.0.0" from react-native@0.64.3
npm WARN     node_modules/react-native

up to date, audited 883 packages in 8s

28 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

5 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

npm version:8.6.0

expo version:5.3.0

Node -v: 16.14.2

react native version: 0.64.3

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

This is an upstream issue in React Native: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33540. You can safely ignore this warning.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. What do you think is the source of the problem?